# Underline Hover on Form Submit Button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I make a hover state, preferably underline, with a Form submit button?

..or would it be easier to incorporate a simple JavaScript Img rollover - Ultimately I just need a hover underline state to assure the user the area is click-able.

**Update:** Currently have;

```
<input type="submit" onClick="javascript:validForm();" value="SUBMIT" class="subbtn" >




input.subbtn {

    width: 75px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color:#F00;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica;
    color:#fff;
    border: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:14px;
}


input.subbtn:hover
{
/* when hover (mouse over)*/
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Why isn't this working; and why does it make it so the little clickable hand isn't displayed anywhere - so the users know even less that the area is clickable.

I just want a hover underline, what am I missing?

Comment: Why do you have a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) in that onclick attribute?

Comment: It's something software I'm using for a Email Sub/Unsub generated and assuming has to do with the functionality provided. Why does that matter?

Comment: — It is a useless waste of space that does nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks - but any advice on the rollover, it's gotta be something easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css to style the buttons, no javascript needed. Make it a normal button:

```
<input type="button" class="button" onClick="javascript:validForm();">
```

And css:

```
input.button
{
/* style it*/
}

input.button:hover
{
/* when hover (mouse over)*/
    cursor:hand;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, styles will apply - but still no hover effect is working?

Comment: Because you didn't add it. Examle: input.button:hover
{
    background: red;
    cursor:hand;
}

Answer (score 0):

try without ".button"
this will apply to all the inputs on oyur page, maybe you must add an "ID".. or maybe not..

```
input {

}

input:hover
{
    cursor:hand;
}
```

Comment: That just applied to the field as well.